# How to extract the exact information of `GenArg`?

Tags: ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, coq

I'm writing a Coq formatter ([code](https://github.com/toku-sa-n/coqfmt/pull/13/files)). So far, I got the AST of a Coq code and pretty-printed a few of its nodes. However, I cannot pretty-print [`VernacExtend`](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/api/coq-core/Vernacexpr/index.html#type-synterp_vernac_expr.VernacExtend) nodes.

The `CoqAst` below represents the AST of `reflexivity.` in `Example foo:1=1. Proof. reflexivity. Qed.`. This representation is generated by [SerAPI](https://github.com/ejgallego/coq-serapi).

```
(Answer 1
 (ObjList
  ((CoqAst
    ((v
      ((control ()) (attrs ())
       (expr
        (VernacExtend (VernacSolve 0)
         ((GenArg (Rawwit (OptArg (ExtraArg ltac_selector))) ())
          (GenArg (Rawwit (OptArg (ExtraArg ltac_info))) ())
          (GenArg (Rawwit (ExtraArg tactic))
           ((v
             (TacArg
              (TacCall
               ((v
                 (((v (Ser_Qualid (DirPath ()) (Id reflexivity)))
                   (loc
                    (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0)
                      (line_nb_last 1) (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 24) (ep 35)))))
                  ()))
                (loc
                 (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0)
                   (line_nb_last 1) (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 24) (ep 35))))))))
            (loc
             (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0) (line_nb_last 1)
               (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 24) (ep 35))))))
          (GenArg (Rawwit (ExtraArg ltac_use_default)) false))))))
     (loc
      (((fname ToplevelInput) (line_nb 1) (bol_pos 0) (line_nb_last 1)
        (bol_pos_last 0) (bp 24) (ep 36)))))))))
```

As shown above, `reflexivity` is wrapped by a `VernacExtend`.

However, [`GenArg`](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/api/coq-core/Genarg/index.html#type-generic_argument) which is inside a `VernacExtend` stores the inner information as a value of type `'a`, instead of a concrete type, making it impossible to analyze the structure.

```ml
type 'l generic_argument = GenArg : ('a, 'l) abstract_argument_type * 'a -> 'l generic_argument
```

How can I convert the type to extract the exact information stored in a `GenArg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a trivial problem, this is why SerAPI / serlib is pretty useful, as you don't want to re-implement this process often.

What serlib does is to register a serializer for each generic argument Coq plugins export. This needs to instrument the plugin loader to load the serializer, and requires custom support for each plugin that extends syntax.

See serlib source code, `serlib/ser_genarg.ml`

There is an issue in SerAPI to discuss a better solution upstream.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact, I considered using SerAPI but was not sure whether I should use it as it is in maintenance mode now (and has been succeeded by `coq-lsp`, but I couldn't use it well either). Actually, I'd like to use some wrapper if possible as parsing a Coq code is very troublesome. What do you think?

Comment: Hi @toku-sa-n, note that the main mechanism taking care of `GenArg` is serlib, not SerAPI; I'll try to make it clearer in the README.

You can use `serlib` from your OCaml program, in many ways, would you like to head to Zulip and discuss more? I'm happy to help.

But basically, you need to take care of two things:
- Using the right `serlib` components or write your own serializers and in `ser_genarg`
- Be sure that you instrument the plugin loader as done in `serapi/*loader`

Comment: I really appreciate your help, @ejgallego. I'll try to rewrite my code with `serlib`. Also, I'll create a thread on Coq Zulip.